# Easiest language/framework to use for web app that follows MVC for someone who has experience with Java/JavaFX

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, web-deployment

I am trying to create a web app that allows the user to browse a noSQL (Preferably MongoDB) database and perform some queries using a graphical interface. All the queries are written in the code and the user only needs to click links and/or enter strings (mostly to search for matches to be displayed in properly formatted tables). The app follows MVC model.
Up until now I used to write similar *desktop* apps  using Java and JavaFX. I have no experience with other languages or frameworks (Aside from C and SDL), neither have I ever deployed anything on a server, and the assignment should be completed within 6 weeks (Three other students are working with me). And I have the three following questions:
Which language/framework is easiest to learn (considering I/we know Java/JavaFX)?
The answer to that would most probably be JavaScript*, which takes me to the next question:Is there any (practical) way that I would make it possible to write the app without having to learn HTML and CSS?
The third and last question, in case I write the View class in JS or Angular, can I write the Controller and Modal with Java (If we disregard complicated workarounds)? And do I deploy all three MVC classes/packages on the same server?

*I believe some would suggest we use GWT or Vaadin, and in this case I wonder if these frameworks have any quirks or limitations that would make it difficult for us as students to work with, be it when it comes to deployment (which is totally new for us) or the writing of the code itself.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered I am posting the best answer I could find so if anyone googles this subject could read it. At last we went with Java for backend running on Tomcat server and JS for front end. It turns out that HTML is very simple and JS is pretty similar to C/Java in syntax.